# 2012_r2 DC VM Guest OS stops responding

Tags: vmware, domain, rpc, esxi5.5

I am experiencing problem on our DC which is a VM hosted inside ESXi 5.5. Upon checking on the event logs I'm seeing this error before the DC stops responding, in which in return I need to restart from ESXi the DC Guest OS for it to be able to run again.

> This computer was not able to set up a secure session with a domain controller in domain XXXXX due to the following: 
>   The RPC server is unavailable. 
>   This may lead to authentication problems. Make sure that this computer is connected to the network. If the problem persists, please contact your domain administrator.

ADDITIONAL INFO

If this computer is a domain controller for the specified domain, it sets up the secure session to the primary domain controller emulator in the specified domain. Otherwise, this computer sets up the secure session to any domain controller in the specified domain.

Comment: This question may get more attention on Server Fault but check to ensure your time on all your DCs is the same as this one, ensure there are no NIC level issues with duplex mismatch, etc. with DC as well. You might also disclose the numbers of DCs in your environment and confirm that you have physical DCs as well and not just all or one VM DC. Tell how you have all these TCP/IP configurations setup on each. Do you have an NTP configuration in your domain? Just some quick ideas but I assume you have firmware for NICs and BIOS updated on the HOST server too, correct?

Comment: Thanks @JUICED_IT, Yes we do NTP config on our domain and all are in the same timing as we have branches from different countries, but only this DC experiencing this problem. 

I havent chek BIOS and NIC firmware if updated,il try to take a look at it...